# Create REGEX of string having 11 to 13 digits

Tags: regex

Creating a regex for phone number that accepts 11 to 13 digits and + in start " - ( ) and _" within the string.

Here is a regex which i have created that accepts till 11 digits but max isn't set:

```
^((\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]){11,13}$
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your regex accept also "_", " ", "(" and ")" wich you don't ask in the question.

Comment: oh sorry, will update it.

Comment: @DanielE. is right.  Please specify your question fully.  Give us some valid examples.  Also please enter which engine are you using - PCRE, ruby, etc.

Comment: Regarding your requirements only, it would be `^(?=.{11,13}$)\+?\d+(?:-\d+)*$`

Comment: Do you really have to use regular expressions, it is this just your first idea?

Comment: The problem is your nested quantifier `*` inside the capturing group. This makes your regex at least 11 characters long but possibly infinite. Do as @revo suggested. See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6t4Sig/1/debugger) and see the numerous steps needed to complete. This is a case of catastrophic backtracking, really.

Comment: Or if the constraint only should apply to digits: `^(?=\D*(?:\d\D*){11,13}$)\+?\d+(?:-\d+)*$`

Comment: @RolandIllig i want to use it because i want to specify the user for limited thing to use by the user in the field

Comment: Can you use an existing library for validating phone numbers? You surely are not the first to solve this task.

Comment: laravel dosen't provide such library.

Comment: @revo  Thanks for your solution, its working great.

Comment: @RolandIllig Do you think existing libraries are doing the task out of the box using no regular expressions? What are regular expressions for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead to apply the limitation on digits. Then write your pattern to match the actual format:

```
^(?=\+?(?:\d-?){11,13}$)\+?\d+(?:-\d+)*$
```

Regex breakdown:

- `^` Start of input string
- `(?=` Start of positive lookahead

  - `\+?` Match an optional `+`
  - `(?:\d-?){11,13}` Match between 11 to 13 digits, allow dashes
  - `$` End of input string
- `)` End of lookahead
- `\+?\d+` Match `+` optionally then a sequence of digits
- `(?:-\d+)*` Match any number of `-\d+` occurrences
- `$` End of input string

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/5PNjrY/1)